# Trying to print additional information besides a column of values in python

Tags: python, printing

This is the result I get with the code below which was a given, three lines of numbers or the results are one per line

```
300
120
myscreen
```

Here is the code

```
print "content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
print
print"<html><head></head><body>"
print (details['followers'])
print "<br/>"
print (details['friends'])
print "<br/>"
print (details['screen'])
```

As mentioned The above script produces the following result

```
300
120
myscreen
```

What I want is to have these numbers mean something by placing a title above them and define what each result means, in other words place some text in front of the numbers.

I was suggested I should create a table, dropping the obtained values in a second column and create the names on the first column, but no idea how that would be dne

```
                      Results
Number of followers:  300
Number of friends:    120
Name on the screen:   myscreen
```

I have tried different things but I am always receiving a 500 Error, so it means that the script does not understand what I am trying to do

I will appreciate any help you can give me or point me on the right way to learn how to do what I want

Thank you

Javier

Comment: I have tried to put print within quotes,  write words before and after parenthesis with and withou quotes among other

Answer (score 0):

Hi there  after doing a lot of searches I found out what I needed to do

If this is how I got a result,

print (details['screen'])

If I wanted to write in front "name of the screen" and then the result it needs to be written as:

print 'name on the screen:' , (details['screen'])

put your text between single quotes and then put a comma

Hope this saves time to some of you